# What is the difference between post() and sendMessage() for handlers in android

Tags: android

I found some information difference between `post()` and `sendMessage()`

1. Post() − it going to post message from background thread to main
   thread using looper.
2. sendmessage() − if you want to organize what you have sent to ui
   (message from background thread) or ui functions. you should use
   sendMessage().

**Question**: Post() is clear in understanding that we post something from background thread to main thread. But how is sendMessage() different

Comment: `sendMessage` send a `Message` object by which you can check what to do inside `handleMessage`. and It also have the variant with Delay like Post ..

Answer (score 2):

Both `post()` and `sendMessage()` work internally the same way, but For `sendMessage()`, we can pass a message object

### *`EXAMPLES`*

### Using post:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Handler Started", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                initHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initHandler() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Executed in background thread",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


}
```

---

### Using sendMessage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    IncomingHandler msgHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        msgHandler = new IncomingHandler(MainActivity.this);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Handler Started", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                initHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initHandler() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Message msg = msgHandler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("MSG_KEY", "Executed in background thread");
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    msgHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler{

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        Context context;

        public IncomingHandler(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull final Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            final String displayMessage = bundle.getString("MSG_KEY");
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context ,displayMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```